# Are Corvus Glaive and Proxima Midnight married in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In the comics, Earth-616, Corvus Glaive and Proxima Midnight are a married couple. We see them together in *Avengers: Infinity War*, going on the mission to get the Mind Stone together and working in tandem in the Battle of Wakanda. They also seem to care for each other but as Children of Thanos this seems reasonable.

Are they married in the MCU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that they are married in the MCU, it just wasn't made explicit to save on time. Joe Russo explains as such in the *Avengers: Infinity War* directors' commentary track; [quoted below from comicbook](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/avengers-infinity-black-order-proxima-midnight-corvus-glaive-married/):

> "There were earlier drafts of the script with the Black Order, in a more stylized draft where we did backstories for each of them." Russo explained. "Ultimately the movie was getting too crowded, too hard to follow. In the books, there's a backstory between Proxima and Corvus, that they're married. Only hinted at in the slightest way here by the fact that they are paired up to retrieve a stone and the way that she responds when Corvus gets stabbed by Natasha."

Comment: I'd watch that sitcom. "At home with the Glaives"

Comment: He's grumpy because she's used his glaive to cut up a roast hatonk, again. She's grumpy because his brother, Cull Obsidian is always hanging around the house. And of course a special guest appearance from Daddy Thanos rounds out the episode.

Comment: The *books*!? Is he referring to comics?

Comment: @Prometheus comic books aye.

Comment: @Valorum:  I love the episodes where their wacky neighbor Galactus drops by for a bite to eat.

Answer (score 15):

The actor who portrays Corvus Glaive, Michael James Shaw has stated on several occasions that they're married.

> **MJS:** *"You've got four of the Dark Order. Ebony Maw, **Proxima Midnight, who's actually his [Corvus'] wife***
>
> **Melvin Taylor:** *I was wondering like, are they gonna be married in this or are they gonna be like 'children of Thanos' brothers?*
>
> **MJS:** ***We are married in the film, yes.***

That being said, there doesn't appear to be any canon confirmation of this in the film.